# how to find out where the error 500 , Node/ReactJs

Tags: node.js, express, routes, fetch

I would like to explain my problem of the day.

I have an error 500 I cannot find where it comes from.

How can I fix this issue?

my fonction:

```
handleSubmit = (e) => {
e.preventDefault();
const userIdData = { id : e.target.id};
const config = {
  method: "DELETE",
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
  },
  body: JSON.stringify(userIdData), 
};
const url = entrypoint + "/alluserpls";
fetch(url, config)
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(res => {
    if (res.error) {
      alert(res.error);
    } else {
      alert(`ajouté avec l'ID ${res}!`);
    }
  }).catch(e => {
    console.error(e);
  }).finally(() => this.setState({ redirect: true }));}
```

routes :

```
app.delete('/api/alluserpls', (req, res, ) => {
const userId = req.body.id;
const formData = req.body

connection.query('DELETE alluserpls WHERE id = ?',[formData, userId], err => {
if (err) {
  res.status(500).send("Erreur lors de la modification des users");
 } else {
  res.sendStatus(200);
 }
});
});
```

Comment: what is the error? please share the full log of the error

Comment: @AliAsgherBadshah  code: 'ER_PARSE_ERROR',
  errno: 1064,
  sqlMessage: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE id = `id` = ''' at line 1",
  sqlState: '42000',
  index: 0,
  sql: "DELETE alluserpls WHERE id = `id` = ''"
}
DELETE /api/alluserpls 500 15.320 ms - 40

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you try this

```
app.delete('/api/alluserpls', (req, res, ) => {
const userId = req.body.id;
const formData = req.body

 connection.query('DELETE * from alluserpls WHERE id = ?',[ userId], err => {
   if (err) {
     res.status(500).send("Erreur lors de la modification des users");
   } else {
    res.sendStatus(200);
   }
 });
});
```

as you only need to pass the id of the user to delete it

Answer (score 0):

you have an issue in your database query. Your DELETE query is wrong. It should be

> DELETE * from table_name where condition;

```
connection.query('DELETE * from alluserpls WHERE id = ?',[userId], err => {
if (err) {
  res.status(500).send("Erreur lors de la modification des users");
 } else {
  res.sendStatus(200);
 }
});
```